Is it nearly 10 years or already 10 years?
I doubt the translation here.
I mean, it should be なった instead of なる if it's already ten years. Right?


I agree that this translation is off.

I believe this English translation is perfectly correct.

The use of 「なる」 (to become) versus 「なった」 (became) slightly changes the nuance.
Difference Between 「なる」 and 「なった」
「なる」: Indicates a present state or an ongoing process.

Example: 「もう10年になる」 means "It's been 10 years now" or "10 years have
passed as of now." It focuses on the current state.

「なった」: Indicates a completed state or reflects on a past event.

Example: 「もう10年になった」 means "It became 10 years" or "10 years have passed (and you're reflecting on it)." This phrasing often implies looking back on the fact that 10 years have already passed.


What tells us that になる actually refers to the present state and not a future transition? Like, couldn’t sentence #1 also mean “It’ll be ten years already” (if, say, I’m talking about how long I’ll have been at a company by the end of the year)? Or would that meaning be more idiomatically expressed by something like 十年にもなる instead of もう？

@JoshGrosso This type of になる is "present tense" by default. But if it's used like 年末で10年になる ("it will be 10 years by the end of this year"), yes, it can be in "future tense".

@naruto Thanks! Could you clarify what you mean by "this type of になる", i.e. how to tell when a given usage of になる falls into this category?

Technically speaking, there is some ambiguity because the "now" behind なる has a (small) range, but it often doesn't matter.

私達がこの家を買ってからもう十年になる。

The ten-year boundary is in the "now" which can span from the near future to the recent past.
If you mean 3650 days ± ~30 days by "10 years", I think it is perfectly fine to translate it as "it's already been ten years". I think both the English and Japanese expressions accept a small margin here.
"It is going to have been ten years very soon" might be more precise, when you are sure it's in the near future not the recent past, but I think there is no need for it to be that precise, usually.

私達がこの家を買ってからもう十年になった。

The ten-year boundary is already in the past - it's been 10 years, or a bit longer than that, but either way you can say "it's already been ten years". This excludes the future reading.
In general, Japanese language's tenses are past tense (marked with た) and present tense (the rest). Some linguists call the latter non-past, because it can be used for future events. However, to choose the future reading, you usually need to add an explicit time expression in the same sentence, like 来年で, or somewhere in the surrounding sentences.
